# \takeargs{n} = take n arguments and print them, space separated?

Tags: macros, parameters

I'm looking for a command `\takeargs{n}` (in either TeX or LaTeX) such that

```
f \takeargs{n} {x_1} ... {x_n} = f\ x_1\ ...\ x_n
```

, that is (if I understood that part)

```
\takeargs{0} =
\takeargs{n} \sometoken = \ \sometoken \takeargs{n-1}
```

Background: In my document, I define some functions (in Haskell-Syntax, which uses spaces for function application). On my constant striving towards don't-ever-repeat-yourself, I'd like to have newcommands for them defined automatically as I go, so I can write

```
\declarefunction{LaunchRockets}{2}{Coords}{Warhead}{IO ()}
% ^ Prints the function name and type and creates \CallLaunchRockets
% ...
Let $p$ be the target coordinates. Then for a huge boom we could e.g.
do a $\CallLaunchRockets p \Nuclear$ ...
% ^ Expands to $\mycodefont{LaunchRockets}\ p\ \Nuclear$
```

Comment: If you want to specify `n` arguments why not just put the space in manually? Unless the elements (or tokens) are generic of sorts.

Comment: So you want the TeX equivalent of the C command int array[3] = {0,1,2}; except taking functions instead of int, and with a command to print out the whole array?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this (plain-TeX) code?  (Note: I did it in 5 minutes without thorough testing, there might be some bug, but it seems to work.  Also, I used exactly your idea of a tail-recursive structure.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\takeargscount
\def\takeargs#1{%
  \takeargscount=#1
  \ifnum\takeargscount>0
    \expandafter\dotakeargs
  \fi
}
\def\dotakeargs#1{%
  \advance\takeargscount by -1
  \takeargsseparator #1\takeargs{\the\takeargscount}%
}
\def\takeargsseparator{ }


\begin{document}
\takeargs{3}{a}{b}{c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Have I understood your code correctly in that `\expandafter` prevents the `\fi` from coming too early, so `\dotakeargs` can eat the next token?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure (my copy of The TeXbook is at work;)), but expanding `\fi` means that `\dotakeargs` sees the next token instead of `\fi`.  So I think you are exactly right.

Comment: Also, I guess that eTeX's `\numexpr` might help making the code shorter, but I'm not sure (and don't have time to try it now, sorry).  Anyway, I'm glad you like this;).

Comment: And one more thing: instead of `\expandafter`ing after `\fi`, you could use Knuth's `\let\next=...` trick.

Comment: @rainmaker: `{a}`, `{b}`, `{c}` are 3 items. Why then do you need to put `3` to lead them?

Comment: @AhmedMusa: as far as I understood the OP, he wants something like a "macro with a variable number of parameters".  The first parameter is the number of them.  In general, it is not possible to determine when the parameters end without it; even an opening brace need not mean that another parameter is waiting here.  (If we assume that this is the case, we could probably do some `\futurelet` trickery to do it this way, and delimit the parameters by anything non-brace-y, a `\relax` in a pinch.  This is left as an exercise for the reader;P.)